# How to convert this json structure without hard-coding names?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json variable.

```
var x =
    [
        {
            x1_year: 0.73,
            x2_year: 0.84,
            x5_year: 1.37,
            x10_year: 1.88                
        }
    ];
```

I want to convert it to look like this;

```
var y =
    [
        {
            c: [{
                v: "x1_year"
            },
                {
                    v: "0.73"
                }]
        },
        {
            c: [{
                v: "x2_year"
            },
                {
                    v: "0.84"
                }]
        },
        {
            c: [{
                v: "x5_year"
            },
                {
                    v: "1.37"
                }]
        },
        {
            c: [{
                v: "x10_year"
            },
                {
                    v: "1.88"
                }]
        }
    ];
```

I have a solution that makes `y1 === y`. It looks like this;

```
var y1 = [
    {
        c:
        [
            {"v": "x1_year"},
            {"v": x[0].x1_year}
        ]
    },
    {
        c:
            [
                {"v": "x2_year"},
                {"v": x[0].x2_year}
            ]
    },
    {
        c:
            [
                {"v": "x5_year"},
                {"v": x[0].x5_year}
            ]
    },
    {
        c:
            [
                {"v": "x10_year"},
                {"v": x[0].x10_year}
            ]
    }
];
```

Unfortunately, it is a lousy solution. The problem is that my solution hardcodes the names of the keys such as `x1_year`, `x1_year`, `x5_year`, `x10_year`.

I would like to have an improved solution such that the names of the key are not hard-coded. Better still, there can be any number of key-name pairs in `x`. How can this be done, if possible?

Comment: Please show the algorithm ending up a "lousy solution".

Comment: @ Teemu, it is already shown in the question. I was asking for an improved solution.

Comment: You can get the keys in an array using `Object.keys(x[0])`for your first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
var x = [
    {
        x1_year: 0.73,
        x2_year: 0.84,
        x5_year: 1.37,
        x10_year: 1.88
    }
];
var y = [];
Object.keys(x[0]).forEach(function(key) {
    y.push({
        c: [
            {v: key},
            {v: x[0][key]}
        ]
    })
});
```

Comment: I do not quite understand this syntax. `Object.keys(x[0]).forEach(function(key)`. Is `key` a keyword to represent key of a key-value pair? Can `key` be replaced by other variable keys?

Comment: @user3293156 `key` it's just a variable. It can be whatever you want: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
`Object.keys(x[0])`-returns all the keys in `x[0]` into array, then you iterate them using `forEach`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
var temp = [];
x.forEach(function(y) {

    for (var i in y) {
        var temp1 = []
        temp1.push({
            'v': i
        });
        temp1.push({
            'v': y[i]
        });
        temp.push({
            'c': temp1
        });
    }

});
console.log(temp);
```

**Snippet**

```js
var x =
    [
        {
            x1_year: 0.73,
            x2_year: 0.84,
            x5_year: 1.37,
            x10_year: 1.88                
        }
    ];

var temp=[];
x.forEach(function(y){

  
  
  for(var i in y){
    var temp1=[]
    temp1.push({'v':i});
    temp1.push({'v':y[i]});
    temp.push({'c': temp1});
  }
  

});

console.log(temp);
```